# How can i kill ppid=1 zombie process with postgresql16?

Tags: postgresql, zombie-process

I have encountered an issue following the establishment of a server using PostgreSQL 16, alongside the creation of numerous tables via pgAdmin 4. In an attempt to rectify a problem, I proceeded to delete the server through pgAdmin. However, this action has led to a more significant issue: the emergence of a zombie process, which has now acquired a parent process ID (PPID) of 1. I suspect that the automated startup mechanism of PostgreSQL 16, or perhaps the method I employed to delete the server, may be contributing factors to this dilemma.

I am seeking guidance on how to effectively terminate this zombie process. Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That cannot be a zombie, because zombies are already dead, and any `init` process will reap them immediately. You should ask a much more detailed question, but not here, because your question is not about software development.